# Where GeoServer store all users data?

Tags: geoserver

I'm learning how use GeoServer in production. There is a thing that isn't clear for me: where GeoServer saves all the users data?
I know that there is the `data` folder inside `webapps/geoserver/`, I use it, but this is the only one place?
For example there is a Disk Quota settings that give the possibility to use PostgreSQL or Oracle instead of H2 DB. Normally I put this option disabled then I don't need to use the H2 DB or other type. How GeoServer remembers the association between user and layers? There is a file or a DB?

Comment: The config is stored in the data directory

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton :)
If add your comment ad an answer I can vote you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of "data" that GeoServer concerns itself with. Data data (vectors, rasters etc) which can be stored anywhere (including other machines in the case of databases) and configuration data that is stored in the data directory (in most cases).